# Why does my page look different, when I hashlink to an ID?

Tags: css, url

I have a quite strange CSS problem.

When I link to my page, the headline (Ohne Geschäftsidee...) looks OK: [blah.html](http://www.xn--existenzgrnder-im-netz-1lc.de/blog/ohne-geschaeftsidee-koennen-sie-nicht-starten-der-startfaktor.html)

But when I append a link to an ID, the top of the headline is cut off: [blah.html#comment-2](http://www.xn--existenzgrnder-im-netz-1lc.de/blog/ohne-geschaeftsidee-koennen-sie-nicht-starten-der-startfaktor.html#comment-2)

However, this doesn't happen when I hashlink to the headline itself: [blah.html#post-199](http://www.xn--existenzgrnder-im-netz-1lc.de/blog/ohne-geschaeftsidee-koennen-sie-nicht-starten-der-startfaktor.html#post-199)

Any ideas how I can stop that madness?

Comment: do you mind showing example code of your css and ids??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird indeed. It seems in the problematic case, the `#main` element overflows its height and since it has an `overflow:hidden;` CSS declaration, the `h1` element is truncated.

Removing the `overflow:hidden;` declaration from the `#main` element seems to solve the truncation.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved by removing "overflow:hidden;" from #main.